# layer-list with item drawable programatically

Tags: android, layer-list

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/back" />
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid/>
            <stroke 
                android:width="1dip" 
                android:color="#228886" />
            <corners android:radius="5dip"/>
            <padding 
                android:left="0dip" 
                android:top="0dip" 
                android:right="0dip" 
                android:bottom="0dip" />
        </shape>
    </item> 
</layer-list>
```

I have the xml like this how can I do it programatically?

Answer (score 0):

use [LayerDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html#LayerDrawable%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%5B%5D%29) Class. In The constructure you can provide a array of `Drawable`. Pass there a [Drawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html) and a [ShapeDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ShapeDrawable.html)

I haven't tried it though, but I think it should work

Comment: hey i found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7150593/android-how-to-define-shapedrawables-programmatically is this similar to what you are telling about