# set background color dynamically

Tags: android

I want to set background color **dynamically** but the colour is actually a gradient which is in a xml

**bg_color.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item><shape>
        <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#f58c0f" android:startColor="#edbc7a" />

        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#929292" />

        <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" />
    </shape></item>
```

which is inside **drawable** folder

**how to set this xml as background.**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7150593/android-how-to-define-shapedrawables-programmatically. might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_color)

Answer (score 1):

you just need to pass that "drawable" file name as a resource

```
yourview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_xml_drawable_file_name);
```

in your case

```
textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_color);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
TextView et = new TextView(activity);
et.setText("350");
et.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(//some color));
```

Comment: I want to add a custom xml (gradient) as a background not a normal color

Comment: et.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.ab);

Comment: @bumba did you check the link i posted?